# MongoDB Select Values above Average

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework

I am trying to find the products whose price is above the average price.

I know how to get the average:

```
db.products.aggregate([{ 
  "$group": {
    "_id": null, 
    "average": { "$avg": "$price" } 
  }
},
{ $project : { _id : 0 } } ])
```

But how can I use it in a $gt clause?

For instance, I tried to save the result in a variable:

```js
var averageValue = 
db.products.aggregate([{ 
  "$group": {
    "_id": null, 
    "average": { "$avg": "$price" } 
  }
},
{ $project : { _id : 0 } } ])
```

And then use it in the $gt clause:

```
db.products.find({ "price": { "$gt": averageValue} })
```

However, it does not seem to print me anything.

I am also wondering if this is possible to be done in a single query.

Answer (score 1):

If you use MongoDB version 5.0, you can use [`$setWindowFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setWindowFields/) to perform the average for all documents in the collection and add the field with result to each document.

> Performs operations on a specified span of documents in a collection, known as a window, and returns the results based on the chosen window operator.

```
db.products.aggregate([
  {
    "$setWindowFields": {
      "output": {
        "average": {
          "$avg": "$price"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $gt: [
          "$price",
          "$average"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/J87m0FIRIWU)